# How to get, size in bytes, MinValue, MaxValue of numeric primitives data types at runtime

Tags: c#, types

I have the below code. What I am trying to achieve, is show various information about numeric primitive *data types* I have in an *array*. Text between double asterisks needs to be gleaned somehow at runtime.

I am assuming there must be table in memory of types, their sizes, and the min and max value ect.

I know this can be done manually, but is there a way I can iterate through them programmatically?

```
// sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, decimal
string[] t = {"sbyte", "byte", "short", "ushort", "int", "uint", "long", "ulong", "float", "double", "decimal"};

Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("| {0, -10} {1, 20} {2, 20} {3, 20} |", "Type", "Byte(s) of memory", "Min", "Max");
Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");

foreach (var i in t)
{                
    Console.Write("| {0, -10} {1, 20} {2, 20} {3, 20} |\n", i, **"bytes in memory", "min", "max"**);
}

Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Your problem statement isn't clear to me. Have you posted the entire assignment, word for word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with some reflection and `Marshal.SizeOf` (in this specific situation)

Probably the easiest way to do this is start of with actual types (E.g `typeof(sbyte)`) in an array.

From there we can use [`Marshal.SizeOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?view=net-5.0) which returns the unmanaged size in bytes, of a class or struct.

<sub>***Note** : you would usually call `sizeof(type)` but this a compile time language feature.*</sub>

<sub>***Also note** : the unmanaged and managed sizes of an object can differ, however in this case they will be what you want.*</sub>

We will need to create an instance of the type with [`Activator.CreateInstance(type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-5.0) to pass to `Marshal.SizeOf`

The last hurdle, will be to get each numeric primitives `MinValue` and `MaxValue` which they all have a constant. We can do this via [`FieldInfo.GetValue(Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?view=net-5.0)

```
var types = new[] {typeof(sbyte), typeof(byte), typeof(short), typeof(ushort), typeof(int), typeof(uint), typeof(long), typeof(ulong), typeof(float), typeof(double), typeof(decimal)};

Console.WriteLine("| {0, -10} | {1, 7} | {2, 30} | {3, 30} |", "Type", "Byte(s)", "Min", "Max");
Console.WriteLine("|------------|---------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|");
foreach (var type in types)
{
   Console.WriteLine(
      "| {0, -10} | {1, 7} | {2, 30} | {3, 30} |",
      type.Name,
      Marshal.SizeOf(Activator.CreateInstance(type)),
      type.GetField("MinValue").GetValue(null),
      type.GetField("MaxValue").GetValue(null));
}
```

<sub>***Note** : I modified your ascii table to comform to the new StackExchange table markdown... why not `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`*</sub>

**Console**

```
| Type       | Byte(s) |                            Min |                            Max |
|------------|---------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
| SByte      |       1 |                           -128 |                            127 |
| Byte       |       1 |                              0 |                            255 |
| Int16      |       2 |                         -32768 |                          32767 |
| UInt16     |       2 |                              0 |                          65535 |
| Int32      |       4 |                    -2147483648 |                     2147483647 |
| UInt32     |       4 |                              0 |                     4294967295 |
| Int64      |       8 |           -9223372036854775808 |            9223372036854775807 |
| UInt64     |       8 |                              0 |           18446744073709551615 |
| Single     |       4 |                 -3.4028235E+38 |                  3.4028235E+38 |
| Double     |       8 |       -1.7976931348623157E+308 |        1.7976931348623157E+308 |
| Decimal    |      16 | -79228162514264337593543950335 |  79228162514264337593543950335 |
```

**New table markdown**

| Type | Byte(s) | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SByte | 1 | -128 | 127 |
| Byte | 1 | 0 | 255 |
| Int16 | 2 | -32768 | 32767 |
| UInt16 | 2 | 0 | 65535 |
| Int32 | 4 | -2147483648 | 2147483647 |
| UInt32 | 4 | 0 | 4294967295 |
| Int64 | 8 | -9223372036854775808 | 9223372036854775807 |
| UInt64 | 8 | 0 | 18446744073709551615 |
| Single | 4 | -3.4028235E+38 | 3.4028235E+38 |
| Double | 8 | -1.7976931348623157E+308 | 1.7976931348623157E+308 |
| Decimal | 16 | -79228162514264337593543950335 | 79228162514264337593543950335 |

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, +1

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what i wanted. I spent a lot of time in solving it with sizeof(type) but it always throw error. thanks a lot.